# Convert QueryDict in Django to an array of object

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I am passing array of object within the ajax like this:

```
function sendAjax(ajax_data) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/ajaxprocess/',
    data: ajax_data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      if (data.status) {
        console.log(data.msg);
      } else {
        console.log("Not success in ajax operation!")
      }
    }
  })
}

function setResult(word, qType, result) {
  resObj = {word: word, qType: qType, result: result}
  allResults.push(resObj)
}
function sendResults() {
  jsonData = sendAjax({
    'type': "results",
    'results': allResults,
  })
}
```

Then it would be expressed like this in backend side:

```
>>> print(request.GET)

<QueryDict: {'type': ['results'], 'results[0][word]': ['hello'], 'results[0][qType]': ['Meaning'], 'results[0][result]': ['true'], 'results[1][word]': ['okay'], 'results[1][qType]': ['Meaning'], 'results[1][result]': ['false'], 'results[2][word]': ['show'], 'results[2][qType]': ['Meaning'], 'results[2][result]': ['true']}>
```

How can I change this QueryDict such that I can use it in backend side separately like a list of objects:

```
for res in results:
   # do something like print(res.word)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the way of passing data within the ajax converted in json format by `JSON.stringify();` function:

```
allResults.push(JSON.stringify(Obj))
```

it would be displayed like this:

```
<QueryDict: {'type': ['results'], 'results[]': ['{"word":"hello","qType":"Meaning","result":true}', '{"word":"okay","qType":"Meaning","result":false}', '{"word":"show","qType":"Meaning","result":true}']}>
```

And then, converting by `json.loads()` function, they are accessible like the Python dictionary:

```
import json
results = request.GET.getlist('results[]')
for res in results:
    print(json.loads(res)['word'])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
results = request.GET['results']

for i in results:
    #make something
```

If this don't work, I'm pretty sure this one does:

```
results = request.GET.get('results')

for i in results:
    #make something
```

Ok, so, have a look at what you're recieving on your request.GET:

{'type': ['results'], 'results[0][word]': ['hello'], 'results[0][qType]': ['Meaning'], 'results[0][result]': ['true'], 'results[1][word]': ['okay'], 'results[1][qType]': ['Meaning'], 'results[1][result]': ['false'], 'results[2][word]': ['show'], 'results[2][qType]': ['Meaning'], 'results[2][result]': ['true']}

As you can see, you can access something like request.GET.get('type'), or request.GET.get('results[0][word]'). But not request.GET.get('results'). Just because the way you're passing it in the javascript.

Comment: No! First one returns error and second one fills results with none.